# i want to pass list as a parameter in hibernateTemplate.find() method but get confused, how to do this? Here is code:

Tags: hibernate, hql

I want to pass list of object to the Query as parameter, that should give list of  object from DB using DAO ,i am new i hibernate so get confused how to do this.

```java
public List<Channel> getBouquets(String[] channelCode) {     
        Session session=hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Query q1=   session.createQuery("select distinct ch.channel from Channel ch where ch.channelCode in(:channelCode)");
        q1.setParameter("channelCode", channelCode);
        q1.setParameterList("channelCode", channelCode);
    System.out.println(q1.list()+"---channels in DAO by pasisng list-----");    
        return q1.list();
    }

org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: channel of: com.concretepage.entity.Channel [select distinct ch.channel from com.concretepage.entity.Channel ch where ch.channelCode in(:channelCode)]
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:298)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your codes look correct as you have already used `setParameterList()` to configure a list of parameter.

The error is because your query `select distinct ch.channel from Channel ch.....`, there is  no `channel` fields in the `Channel` Java entity. If you just want to select all fields of the `Channel` entity , you can simply use `select distinct ch from Channel ch....`.

Moreover , you need to consider the case that when `channelCode` is empty or null in order for constructing the query. Depending on what you want , you can simply throw exception or assume there is no restriction on the channel code.

Furthermore , you can supply a class parameter in `createQuery()` to have a type-safe `Query` which you don't need to manually cast back the object to the `Channel`.

Last but not least , you should use `HibernateTemplate#execute()` to execute the query if you want to use the Spring goodies such as to ensure the session is automatically closed at the end etc....

Code wise it looks like:

```java
hibernateTemplate.execute(session->{
   String query = "select distinct ch.channel from Channel ch ";
   if(channelCode.length() > 0){
      query = query + " where ch.channelCode in (:channelCode) "; 
   }

   Query<Channel> q1= session.createQuery(query , Channel.class);
   if(channelCode.length() > 0){
      q1.setParameterList("channelCode", channelCode);
   }
   return q1.getResultList();
});
```